# Trying to figure out how to interface with the PayGate API

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I can see that these are the parameters required when I make a call to the payment gateway API, but I have no idea how I would implement this in Javascript (specifically React). Any translators able to lend a hand?

Here is the example code in PHP:

```
$encryptionKey = 'secret';

$DateTime = new DateTime();

$data = array(
    'PAYGATE_ID'        => 10011072130,
    'REFERENCE'         => 'pgtest_123456789',
    'AMOUNT'            => 3299,
    'CURRENCY'          => 'ZAR',
    'RETURN_URL'        => 'https://my.return.url/page',
    'TRANSACTION_DATE'  => $DateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'LOCALE'            => 'en-za',
    'COUNTRY'           => 'ZAF',
    'EMAIL'             => 'customer@paygate.co.za',
);

$checksum = md5(implode('', $data) . $encryptionKey);

$data['CHECKSUM'] = $checksum;

$fieldsString = http_build_query($data);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I have been trying to use axios to make the request, but any method will do. I was trying to create an axios instance like so:

````
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans',
    headers:{
      //I guess this is where PAYGATE_ID etc would go, but I'm not sure how to format it
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For React, the way to handle this is to generate an MD5 checksum and append it to the payload before sending, probably using CryptoJS or something. I created this function to generate the MD5:

```
const generateMD5 = (obj, secret = 'paygateSecret') => {
    let str = ''
    for (let val in obj){
        str += obj[val]
    }
    
    str += secret

    return CryptoJS.MD5(str).toString()
}
```

I have an object that contains my data:

```
var data = {
      PAYGATE_ID: 10011072130,
      REFERENCE: ref,
      AMOUNT: amount,
      CURRENCY: 'ZAR',
      RETURN_URL: window.location.href,
      TRANSACTION_DATE: new Date().toISOString(),
      LOCALE: 'en-za',
      COUNTRY: 'ZAF',
      EMAIL: email,
}
```

Please note the order. It is very important.
Then, I generate the checksum using:

```
const CHECKSUM = generateMD5(data)
```

And then make the axios call:

```
axios.post('https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans', { ...data, CHECKSUM }).then(...).catch(...)
```

I think this should work!

Comment: I'm using this solution but it doesn't seem to work. Give "ERROR=DATA_CHK" error.